# Delayed Chained Payment - Payment must occur within 90 Days

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

As per the developer's guide, the payment to the secondary receivers must occur within 90 days, after which you cannot complete the payment as part of original chained payment. 
MY question is how to transfer funds to secondary receivers if 90 days period to fund transfer lapsed? 
DO I have to refund the funds back to the sender(buyer) and set the Adaptive payment process again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming - it is about paypal system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refund the money and start process again. Primary receiver can manually send the money to the secondary receiver , refer to https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ1684&m=HTQ , but PayPal will charge transaction fee on this.